# Responsive Jquery Upload preview div

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive

I am using this awesome [upload Preview jQuery plugin](http://opoloo.github.io/jquery_upload_preview/) but I am having a hard time making it mobile responsive.
I have tried adding the img-responsive class, setting max width and some other things i have found on the Internet but no luck.

Is there a way I can make this div responsive as the page is shrinking?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="image-preview">
        <label for="image-upload" id="image-label">Choose File</label>
        <input type="file" name="primary-item-photo" id="image-upload" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#image-preview {
    max-height: 320px;
    max-width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    width: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("../../images/icons/primary-photo-default.PNG");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
 $.uploadPreview({
        input_field: "#image-upload",
        preview_box: "#image-preview",
        label_field: "#image-label"
    });
```

Comment: you can set `max-width:320px` then have `width: 100%`

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or codepen link with working code?

Comment: Set the width to 100%, max-width will act as the boundary.